# Raspberry PI 3 B end of life

Tags: pi-3

I am using several Raspberry PI 3 B for embedded applications. Given the release of the new PI 3 B +, I am now concerned about for how long the PI 3 B will be available. 
What is the expected end of life of the 3 B model ?
Do I need to start migrating to 3 B + pretty soon or I still have some years ?
Thank you very much in advance
Guillermo

Comment: Please contact the manufacturer(s).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't super easy to answer with any kind of guaranteed answer, but they did touch on this during the 3B+'s release post on the [official blog](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/raspberry-pi-3-model-bplus-sale-now-35/).

> **Are you discontinuing earlier Raspberry Pi models?**
>
> No. We have a lot of industrial customers who will want to stick with
>   the existing products for the time being. We’ll keep building these
>   models for as long as there’s demand. Raspberry Pi 1B+, Raspberry Pi
>   2B, and Raspberry Pi 3B will continue to sell for $25, $35, and $35
>   respectively.

They offered similar answers when the other models had upgrades available, and they're still making most of those. Personally, I'd expect the 3B to be around for a while yet.

Comment: "Raspberry Pi 1B+, Raspberry Pi 2B, and Raspberry Pi 3B will continue to sell for $25, $35, and $35 respectively." - unless you are in Australia, where the older models sell for considerably MORE than the newer ones!! like $70 for a Pi2!!!

Comment: Yeah - they still think of you guys as part of the colonial empire, so it's OK to gouge a bit  :)

Answer (score 3):

I've asked the charity for the EOL date of the **pi-3b** by email and today's answer was:

> Raspberry Pi 3 Model B will remain in production until at least January
>   2022.

---

By the way: For the following devices is an ["obsolescence statement"](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/product_categories/raspberry-pi-boards/) publicly available:

**pi-zero**

> End of life of the Raspberry Pi Zero is currently stated as being not before January 2022

**pi-3b+**

> will remain in production until at least January 2023

Answer (score 3):

Now the "Obsolescence Statement" is specified on product`s page (almost in the bottom):

**RPI 3B**

- https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-3-model-b/
- "Raspberry Pi 3 Model B will remain in production until at least January 2026"

**RPI 3B+**

- https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-3-model-b-plus/
- "Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+ will remain in production until at least January 2026"